# To graphically display the distribution of one variable by another, which is X and which is Y?

Tags: r

To answer the question: Graphically display the distribution of A by B, should I do:

```
plot(table$A,table$B)
```

Or:

```
plot(table$B,table$A)
```

Sorry for asking such a simple question, I have never done stats before!

Comment: Try `plot(1:10, 5*1:10)`. Also, you could take a look at `help(plot)`.

Comment: The `?plot` help page seems to make this pretty clear. Make sure to check the documentation for functions first if you have questions about them.

Comment: I think that the question is really a question about language. What does "by" mean?  Check out [This discussion](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107800/is-x-plotted-against-y-or-is-y-plotted-against-x)